# Using Python and lxml to strip only the tags that have certain attributes/values

Tags: python, lxml

I'm familiar with etree's `strip_tags` and `strip_elements` methods, but I'm looking for a straightforward way of stripping tags (and leaving their contents) that only contain particular attributes/values.

For instance: I'd like to strip all `span` or `div` tags (or other elements) from a tree (`xhtm`l) that have a `class='myclass'` attribute/value (preserving the element's contents like `strip_tags` would do). Meanwhile, those same elements that *don't* have `class='myclass'` should remain untouched.

Conversely: I'd like a way to strip all "naked" `spans` or `divs` from a tree. Meaning only those `spans`/`divs` (or any other elements for that matter) that have absolutely *no* attributes. Leaving those same elements that *have* attributes (any) untouched.

I feel I'm missing something obvious, but I've been searching without any luck for quite some time.

Answer (score 14):

## HTML

`lxml`s HTML elements have a method [`drop_tag()`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-element-methods) which you can call on any element in a tree parsed by `lxml.html`.

It acts similar to `strip_tags` in that it removes the element, but retains the text, and it can be called *on* the element - which means you can easily select the elements you're not interested in with an [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) expression, and then loop over them and remove them:

**`doc.html`**

```xml
<html>
    <body>
        <div>This is some <span attr="foo">Text</span>.</div>
        <div>Some <span>more</span> text.</div>
        <div>Yet another line <span attr="bar">of</span> text.</div>
        <div>This span will get <span attr="foo">removed</span> as well.</div>
        <div>Nested elements <span attr="foo">will <b>be</b> left</span> alone.</div>
        <div>Unless <span attr="foo">they <span attr="foo">also</span> match</span>.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**`strip.py`**

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml import html

doc = html.parse(open('doc.html'))
spans_with_attrs = doc.xpath("//span[@attr='foo']")

for span in spans_with_attrs:
    span.drop_tag()

print etree.tostring(doc)
```

**Output:**

```xml
<html>
    <body>
        <div>This is some Text.</div>
        <div>Some <span>more</span> text.</div>
        <div>Yet another line <span attr="bar">of</span> text.</div>
        <div>This span will get removed as well.</div>
        <div>Nested elements will <b>be</b> left alone.</div>
        <div>Unless they also match.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this case, the XPath expression `//span[@attr='foo']` selects all the `span` elements with an attribute `attr` of value `foo`. See this [XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) for more details on how to construct XPath expressions.

## XML / XHTML

**Edit**: *I just noticed you specifically mention XHTML in your question, which according to the docs is better parsed as XML. Unfortunately, the `drop_tag()` method is really only available for elements in a HTML document.*

So for XML it's a bit more complicated:

**`doc.xml`**

```xml
<document>
    <node>This is <span>some</span> text.</node>
    <node>Only this <span attr="foo">first <b>span</b></span> should <span>be</span> removed.</node>
</document>
```

**`strip.py`**

```
from lxml import etree


def strip_nodes(nodes):
    for node in nodes:
        text_content = node.xpath('string()')

        # Include tail in full_text because it will be removed with the node
        full_text = text_content + (node.tail or '')

        parent = node.getparent()
        prev = node.getprevious()
        if prev:
            # There is a previous node, append text to its tail
            prev.tail += full_text
        else:
            # It's the first node in <parent/>, append to parent's text
            parent.text = (parent.text or '') + full_text
        parent.remove(node)


doc = etree.parse(open('doc.xml'))
nodes = doc.xpath("//span[@attr='foo']")
strip_nodes(nodes)

print etree.tostring(doc)
```

**Output:**

```xml
<document>
    <node>This is <span>some</span> text.</node>
    <node>Only this first span should <span>be</span> removed.</node>
</document>
```

As you can see, this will replace node *and* all its children with the recursive text content. I really hope that's what you want, otherwise things get even more complicated ;-)

**NOTE** Last edit have changed the code in question.

Comment: Yes. It's unfortunate a similar method doesn't exist for XML parsed elements. Your suggestion is definitely something to keep in mind, but since I'm always going to be working with validated xhtml (complete with DTD and entities), the work to prepare the source for the HTML parser (plus the work to get the result back into xhtml) seems a bit prohibitive.

Comment: Yeah. I kept the answer because I think it could be helpful to someone else, but I see how this doesn't work for you. Maybe you could adapt the idea for XML: Still use XPath to query for the elements to remove, but replace them yourself with a text representation of their contents (using XPath `string()` or `etree.tostring(node, method="text"`). But since `lxml` doesn't use text nodes, but `text` and `tail` instead, this might get a bit tricky.

Comment: @BushLeague I gave that a try, see my updated answer.

Comment: That's given me something to chew on. I have to deal with the xhtml namespace, but I have a handle on that. The real problem is that I need any children that may be nested within that span to be retained. The 'b' tags were lost in that last stab at it. In your code.xml snippet, I need _everything_ else to remain the same. I literally need the `<span attr="foo">` and its closing tag to just go away leaving everything else it they have contained (text and/or children) the same.

Comment: Then you do have in fact your work cut out for you. Possibly a combination of `node.itertext()` and `node.iterchildren()` could be helpful, but it still will be rather messy. Oh, and yes, namespace handling (especially default NS) in XPath 1.0 is tedious to say the least - I've been there. At this point, I can only wish you good luck (or hope that someone else knows a clean way that we missed).

Comment: I appreciate the help. I'll be certain to update if I do discover an answer. I may update the question so as to not limit the answer to lxml. I'm open to other python solutions/modules if there's something out there that would make it "easier." Thanks again.

Comment: I miss main idea, can you use something like this `lxml.cssselect.CSSSelector`? And what is output content, will it be rendered as html or no?

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem, and after some cosideration had this rather hacky idea, which is borrowed from regex-ing Markup in Perl onliners: How about first catching all unwanted Elements with all the power that `element.iterfind` brings, renaming those elements to something unlikely, and then strip all those elements?

Yes,this isn't absolutely clean and robust, as you always might have a document that actually uses the "unlikely" tag name you've chosen, but the resulting code IS rather clean and easily maintainable. If you really need to be sure that whatever "unlikely" name you've picked doesn't exist already in the document, you can always check for it's existing first, and do the renaming only if you can't find any pre-existing tags of that name.

**doc.xml**

```
<document>
    <node>This is <span>some</span> text.</node>
    <node>Only this <span attr="foo">first <b>span</b></span> should <span>be</span> removed.</node>
</document>
```

**strip.py**

```
from lxml import etree
xml = etree.parse("doc.xml")
deltag ="xxyyzzdelme"
for el in xml.iterfind("//span[@attr='foo']"):
    el.tag = deltag
etree.strip_tag(xml, deltag)
print(etree.tostring(xml, encoding="unicode", pretty_print=True))
```

**Output**

```
<document>
     <node>This is <span>some</span> text.</node>
     <node>Only this first <b>span</b> should <span>be</span> removed.</node>
</document>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. But in my case the scenario a little easier, I have an option - not remove tags, just clear it, our users see rendered html and if I have for example

```
<div>Hello <strong>awesome</strong> World!</div>
```

I want to clear `strong` tag by css selector `div > strong` and save tail context, in lxml you cant use `strip_tags` with `keep_tail` by selector, you can strip only by tag, it makes me crazy. And more over if you just remove `<strong>awesome</strong>` node, you also remove this tail - "World!", text that wrapped `strong` tag.
Output will be like:

```
<div>Hello</div>
```

For me ok this:

```
<div>Hello <strong></strong> World!</div>
```

No **awesome** for the user anymore.

```
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(markup)
selector = lxml.cssselect.CSSSelector('div > strong')
for el in list(selector(doc)):
    if el.tail:
        tail = el.tail
        el.clear()
        el.tail = tail
    else:
        #if no tail, we can safety just remove node
        el.getparent().remove(el)
```

You can adapt the code with physical delete `strong` tag with the call `element.remove(child)` and attach it tail to the parent, but for my case it was overhead.