# How to match the content with only the attribute value.?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to match the content only with the attribute value. For example following data I am having

```
<div id='cont'>blablabla</div>

<span class='cont newClass'>blablabla</div>

<someothertag name='cont'>blablabla</div>
```

From the above I want to match all tags which contain the attrvalue `cont`

To match the any tag I have used the RegEx, as below

```
soup.find_all(re.compile(r'.*'),{"class":re.compile(r".*cont.*")}):
               --------------             ------------------------
                Match any tag              match with the string cont
```

But I don't know how to make the regex for attribute name means `class,id,name,etc.`

If suppose I will go with pure regex it won't  match the values, like as follow

```
re.findall(r'<[^>]*cont[^>]*>.+?<\/\1>',str(soup))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Python and lxml to strip only the tags that have certain attributes/values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685795/using-python-and-lxml-to-strip-only-the-tags-that-have-certain-attributes-values)

Comment: It's not a duplicate because in this one he appears to be using BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not possible to do it straightaway. You could pass a callback to `find_all` and do the processing there. Something like this (not tested):

```
def checker(tag):
    for attr_val in tag.attrs.values():
        if 'cont' in attr_val:
            return True

    return False

soup.find_all(checker)
```

Comment: You can also use `lambda` to make it shorter, `soup.find_all(lambda tag: any('cont' in attr for attr in tag.attrs.values()))`.